# Delphi function, Not allowing files and folders from main directory during compression

Tags: delphi, function, procedure

I used this code to combined all files into one from a directory, not really compression,

```
procedure CompressDirectory(InDir : string; OutStream : TStream);
var
AE : TArchiveEntry;
procedure RecurseDirectory(ADir : string);
var
sr : TSearchRec;
TmpStream : TStream;
begin
if FindFirst(ADir + '*', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
begin
repeat
if (sr.Attr and (faDirectory or faVolumeID)) = 0 then
begin
// We have a file (as opposed to a directory or anything
// else). Write the file entry header.
AE.EntryType := aeFile;
AE.FileNameLen := Length(sr.Name);
AE.FileLength := sr.Size;
OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
OutStream.Write(sr.Name[1], Length(sr.Name));
// Write the file itself
TmpStream := TFileStream.Create(ADir + sr.Name, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
OutStream.CopyFrom(TmpStream, TmpStream.Size);
TmpStream.Free;
end;
if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) > 0 then
begin
if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
begin
// Write the directory entry
AE.EntryType := aeDirectory;
AE.DirNameLen := Length(sr.Name);
OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
OutStream.Write(sr.Name[1], Length(sr.Name));
// Recurse into this directory
RecurseDirectory(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ADir + sr.Name));
end;
end;
until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
FindClose(sr);
end;
// Show that we are done with this directory
AE.EntryType := aeEOD;
OutStream.Write(AE, SizeOf(AE));
end;
begin
RecurseDirectory(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(InDir));
end;
```

What if I want the compressDirectory function not to include some folders and files? What would be the CompressDirectory function code look like? please guide me, thanks.

> >
>   Edited, removed image for space.

Comment: Don't use JPG for non-photographic images.

Comment: Please learn to properly format your code so that it's readable. If it looks that bad before posting it here, teach yourself to properly indent the code even just for yourself. If you can read it, it's much easier to debug and troubleshoot now, as well as maintain it in the future (especially if you're working with other people or posting it in public and asking others to do so).  If you can't put in the effort to format it for us to read, it's pretty hard for us to have the motivation to spend time trying to help you get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code already employs a technique for skipping certain unwanted file names:

```
if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
```

Simply use that same technique to exclude whatever other files you wish. You can hard-code the exclusion list into the code, as is already done with the *.* and *..* names, or you can pass a list of names into the function as another parameter. Before you add a file to the archive, check whether that file name is in the list of files to exclude.

For example, if the list of excluded names were in a `TStrings` descendant, you might use something like this:

```
if ExcludedNames.IndexOf(sr.Name) >= 0 then
  Continue; // Skip the file because we've been told to exclude it.
```

You could enhance this to check the full path of the file instead of just the local name. You could also enhance it to support wildcards in the list of exclusions.

Comment: OK, I used TStringList, add the path that I don't want to include.  Let me check your code also, thanks.

Comment: Then you'll have to study your code some more. I'm not going to do your job for you. Identify which part of your code is responsible for writing data into a file. The rest of it is responsible for iterating over the files. The former is the part you want to skip sometimes, so make your changes there. If you took some pride in how your code looked, you might indent it properly, and that might make it easier to read.